# Unable to retrieve PayPal success/cancel payment data from redirected urls in JAVA

Tags: java, spring-mvc, paypal, payment-gateway

Code to post PayPal form.

```
<body>
<form accept-charset="utf-8"
    action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/au/cgi-bin/webscr" id="frm"
    method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="business"
        value="aaaa-facilitator@gmail.com"> <input
        type="hidden" name="cancel_return"
        value="http://localhost:8080/abc-jaxrs/web/cancel_redirection"> <input type="hidden"
        name="cmd" value="_xclick"> <input type="hidden"
        name="charset" value="utf-8"> <input type="hidden"
        name="currency_code" value="USD"> <input type="hidden"
        name="notify_url" value="http://localhost:8080/abc-jaxrs/web/success_redirection"> <input
        type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost:8080/abc-jaxrs/web/success_redirection"> <input
        type="hidden" name="item_name" value="123"> <input
        type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.1">
</form>
<p style="text-align: center">
<h4>Redirecting To PayPal...</h4>

<script>
    $(this.document).ready(function() {
        $('.loaderparent').show();
        var frm = $("form");
        frm.submit();
    });
</script>
```

Code to retrieve data from data from Java controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/success_redirection", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView successRedirection(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    String itemName = (String) request.getAttribute("item_name"); // or
    String itemNname = request.getParameter("item_name");
}
```

But getting itemName value as null in both cases.

So how to retrieve success/failure data from PayPal in JAVA.

Comment: What does their documentation say ?

Comment: @AmanChhabra Documentation says : With Auto Return turned on in your account profile, you can set the value of the return URL on each individual transaction to override the value that you have stored on PayPal.

return
The URL to which PayPal redirects buyers' browser after they complete their payments. 

cancel_return
A URL to which PayPal redirects the buyers' browsers if they cancel checkout before completing their payments.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure enabling the **Instant Payment Notification (IPN)** from paypal account setting along with the success URL.

`My Profile > My Selling Tools> Instant payment notifications >update` then like below.

[image]